# Why does subsetting change with tbl_df in dlpyr?

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr

I've discovered some strange behaviour when sub-setting with dplyr tbl_df data frames. When I subset a data-frame with the `'matrix' style df[,'a']` it returns a vector as expected. However when I do the same thing when it's a `tbl_df` data frame, it returns a data frame instead.

I've replicated it below using the Iris data set.

Can some-one explain why this is happening, or how I can de-tbl_df that data frames? I need to use dplyr and readr in the build-up to needing this behaviour.

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

str(iris['Sepal.Length'])
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...

str(iris[,'Sepal.Length'])
 num [1:150] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...

iris <- tbl_df(iris)

str(iris[,'Sepal.Length'])
Classes ‘tbl_df’ and 'data.frame':  150 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
```

Comment: you can convert back to regular dataframe `data.frame(iris)`, `?tbl_df` never simplifies, always returns `data.frame`

Comment: @nongkrong - the alternative is to use `iris[['Sepal.Length']]` which will work with both `data.frame`s and `tbl_df`s or make an explicit call to subset like a `data.frame` - `\`[.data.frame\`(iris,,'Sepal.Length')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is on purpose.

See `?tbl_df`:

> Methods:
>
> `‘tbl_df’` implements two important base methods:
>
> `print` Only prints the first 10 rows, and the columns that fit on
>             screen
>
> **`‘[’` Never simplifies (drops), so always returns data.frame**

(emphasis added)

If you `class(tbl_df(iris))` you will see that its class is "tbl_df", then "tbl", and finally "data.frame", so it might have a different `[` method, and `methods(class='tbl_df')` indeed shows `[.tbl_df`.

(it's a bit like how datatables in the `data.table` package have a different `[` method too).

---

edit : to un-`tbl_df` , just use `data.frame`, e.g. `data.frame(tbl_df(iris))` will convert the `tbl_df(..)` back to data.frame.

Comment: Great, so it's intentional. Now just to the second part of my question, how can I de-tbl_df my data frames? I can just unclass and then reclass but that seems like a hack.

Comment: Just `data.frame(iris.tbl_df)`.

Comment: Just an editorial comment, I think that this behaviour is bad. I don't see why a pretty-printing wrapper should change the default behaviour of data-frames in an unexpected way.